# I have a error on Incorrect syntax near 'nchar'

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

The error is saying incorrect syntax near nchar this is what visual studio suggests

the error suggests Line 31:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'Name'. 
>   int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar());

my code is below

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
       SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

       conn.Open();
       string checkuser = "select count(*) from [Table] where User Name=@User Name";
       SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);

       com.Parameters.Add("@User Name", SqlDbType.NChar, 20).Value = TextBoxUN.Text;
       int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar());           

       if (temp == 1)
       {
           Response.Write(" USER ALREADY EXISTS ");
       }


       conn.Close(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Just remove the space on your parameter name. Change `@User Name` to `@UserName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try that

```
string checkuser = "select count(*) from [Table] where [User Name]=@UserName"
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);

       com.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NChar, 20).Value = TextBoxUN.Text;
```

You should wrap column names in braces if it has whitespace in it. so the column name User Name should be places in square braces '[]', for the parameter name "@User Name", I don't think that it would accept it neither, you should remove the whitespace in parameter name also.

Comment: Its worth describing what you've changed, it will help with understanding.

Comment: GOT THIS ERROR NOW Error:System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near 'Name'. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClos

Comment: check the parameter name then, you also need to remove the space from the UserName parameter name.

Comment: I Cant find parameter name where is that?

Comment: Parameter name is prefixed with '@' sign.

Answer (score 5):

If your database objects and parameter names you used with them are more than one word, you need to use them square brackets like `[User Name]`

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`.

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
using(SqlCommand com = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    com.CommandText = "select count(*) from [Table] where [User Name] = @UserName";
    com.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NChar, 20).Value = TextBoxUN.Text;
    conn.Open();
    int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar()); 
}
```

As a best practice, *don't* use more than one word for your table or column names.

Comment: And the same for variables with a space.

Comment: @Jamiec Amen. Added as well. Thanks.